# postfix block mail to a domain only for a specific destination domain

Tags: postfix, domain-name, filtering

I have a mail server that hosts many virtual domains.

The owner of one virtual domain that is on this server asked me to block mails coming from an external domain to his mailboxes.

I have this setting in my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfi/sender_check
```

that allow me to block mail from a domain, but if I use this solution, I block mail coming from this sender domain to all the domains in the server and not only for the interested.

Is there any trick to say to postfix to evaluate both sender domain AND destination domain for filtering?

I can filter at mailbox level, but it is annoyng and very time consuming to manage ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `smtpd_restriction_classes` in `main.cf` like this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    ...
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
    ...

smtpd_restriction_classes = tocustomerx
tocustomerx = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/customer_x_sender_access
```

In `/etc/postfix/recipient_access` put something like this:

```
dom-customer.com tocustomerx
```

And in `/etc/postfix/customer_x_sender_access`

```
dom-xyz.com REJECT
```

This tells postfix that mails to your customers domain belong to class `tocustomerx` and that for the class it should check `/etc/postfix/customer_x_sender_access` for the sender access.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

I am trying it.

Can you write an example of what exacly insert in the files if we suppose I want block mail from DOM-XYZ.com to DOM-CUSTOMER.COM?

Thanks, P.

Comment: Hope it helps, don't forget to run `postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_access` and `postmap /etc/postfix/customer_x_sender_access`.

Comment: ;-)
I tried youer soluyion initially without success.

Comment: ;-)  
I tried your solution initially without success.  

I put <at>DOM-CUSTOMER.COM tocustomerx in /etc/postfix/recipient_access   

and   

<at>DOM-XYZ.com             REJECT     
in /etc/postfix/customer_x_sender_access  
mail still pass ...
Searched on the net and found a similar solution in   https://www.arschkrebs.de/postfix/postfix_restriction_classes.shtml  
added the "reject_unauth_destination" to the check_sender_access = ...  row  
Still no result.  
Inserted full mail address (sender and receiver), in both files and it works.

Comment: yeah sorry, it's without the @, I removed it when adding your example domains.

Comment: I have lot of  problems with this editor ...  added to my poor English ... :-)

Sorry. Hope can be understood

Comment: Obviously I am interested to use wildcard o something that  allow me to manage a whole domain ...
Otherwise it is probably simpler to works directly to the mailboxes ... ;-)

Comment: Removed the "@". seems work as exected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that using only Postfix builtin filters, then it can be done only if you can assign different public ip addresses to the postfix server.

If so you can follow this example to get what you want:
[Postfix BUILTIN_FILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html#domain_except)

Or you could write an external filter, following instructions and examples at [Postfix FILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html)

Regards

Paolo B.