# Postfix configuration as relay with another server

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to configure postfix to relay emails sent to mydomain.com to another host (file sharing solution that accepts incoming emails, no other mail server available)

My issue is that it creates a loop : I send an email from hello@gmail.com to user@mydomain.com (gets received fine) and then (as it's a file sharing solution) it will trigger a notification to user@mydomain.com saying that he's got a new mail and this starts a loop (postfix is also the relay used on the file sharing solution to send external emails).

--> file sharing solution (user@mydomain.com) has POSTFIX as smtp relay. Then Postfix is configured to send *@mydomain.com to the file sharing solution. hence the loop

Any idea how to address that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's OK I figured it out.
I wanted the loop to stop and I achieved that by using "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" and "smtpd_restriction_classes" (Postfix discards email sends from sender mydomain.com to recipient mydomain.com).

This post helped my achieving this : [postfix block mail to a domain only for a specific destination domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/785792/postfix-block-mail-to-a-domain-only-for-a-specific-destination-domain)